# Response.Redirect is redirecting to a page that doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, response.redirect

I'm doing a simple check for some user data that get's put into session on sign in. What happens, is I click through a few buttons to get to this page. This page a has a drop down that is set to `autopostback=true`.

When I change my selection in the drop, my request get's redirected to a page that doesn't exist. `signin.aspx` exists in the root folder of the site. The attempted redirect looks for signin in the folder that this particular page is in (example.com/folder1/signin.aspx) instead of example.com/signin.aspx.

Should I be using something other than `Response.Redirect` to accomplish this?

Side note about the application:

This is .net 4 using jquery 1.6.4 and jquerymobile 1.0. I'm thinking jquery mobile is the problem because I use this same pattern/practice on other applications without issue.

> Location of page where this is happening. 
>   example.com/folder1/page2.aspx
>
> location of sign in page:  example.com/signin.aspx
>
> url that displays in the error.  example.com/folder1/signin.aspx

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["UserData"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("../SignIn.aspx");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you also post your markup/aspx code

Comment: More information needed: wich url you are when call thsi method? to wich url  you want go?

Comment: i updated my question.  the redirect should go to signin.aspx in the root of the site.  the redirect is actually trying to take me to a signin page that doesn't exist in folder1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use asp.net style root-relative paths:

```
Response.Redirect("~/SignIn.aspx");
```

That makes the URL relative to your site's root (not the web root unless your site is the web root), but still allows the site to be moved around.

Comment: Apparently they are called 'root-relative'. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Comment: I'm guessing they want rooted path, as the 404 is likely because they are in subdirectory in which parent folder doesn't have SignIn.aspx

Comment: @BNL Ahhh! So we are both right! (and... both wrong... hehe) Good catch, and good edit!

Comment: @DarrenKopp Yes, that's what they seem to want. BNL's answer provides that with an ASP.NET-specific syntax. It works even when the web application in question is installed in a virtual directory as a separate application.

Answer (score 1):

jquery wouldn't be affecting a server side response.redirect. Are you sure that the page exists as it's being set in your code? If signin.aspx is in the root of the website, could you not simply do this?

```
Response.Redirect("/SignIn.aspx");
```

Comment: I removed all of my jquery references and everything worked.  I'm pretty sure that jquery mobile is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{


    if (Session["UserData"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/SignIn.aspx");
    }

}
```